# Unexpected end of JSON input - apex/ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, plsql, oracle-apex

In APEX i have a Dynamic Action that triggers when the page is loaded, it checks if the last page is different from the current page and then it *should* call a proccess with AJAX that clears the page cache with an PL/SQL function

But when i switch to the page theres a big error message:

> Error: parseerror - SyntaXError: Unexpected end of JSON input

But the page cache is cleared after i refresh the page, if i use the PL/SQL function only i dont have to refresh it and all values of the page are empty

I'm fairely new to APEX/SQL and PL/SQL and i have absolutely no idea of JSON

Heres the code that i use in the Dynamic Action to call the process if the page URL is different

```
var ref = document.referrer;
var cur = window.location.href;

if (cur != ref)
{
    apex.server.process('refresh',
        {
            "dataType:":"script"
        }
    );
}
```

Heres the proccess code

```
BEGIN
APEX_UTIL.CLEAR_PAGE_CACHE (NV('APP_PAGE_ID'));
END;
```

For the research i did i found out that is has to be something with the AJAX call in the JavaScript. I switched the dataType to script so when the call succeeds it executes it automatically. What am i missing?

Comment: there's a typo in "datatype:":"script" it should be "datatype":"script"

Comment: @Typo well, didn't thought i'd be that blind :P but unfortunately id didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: try with "dataType":"text"

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the second argument to `apex.server.process`. The first argument is the process name, the second is an object with data to pass to the request, and the third is an object with options to pass to `$.ajax`.
So, to set the dataType:

```
apex.server.process('refresh',
    null,
    {
        "dataType:":"script"
    }
);
```

However... It's really not clear why you'd do this? Why erase session state in your current page through a page-load ajax process? What's the point?